# Почему не отображаются fragment в контейнере?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

В android studio создано приложение с помощью шаблона drawer.
Сделал два фрагмента и сгенерировал разметку для них.
В MainActivity:
Создаю два фрагмента

```
FragmentPipes fragmentPipes;
FragmentTanks fragmentTanks;
```

В onCreate() их инициализирую

```
fragmentPipes = new FragmentPipes();
fragmentTanks = new FragmentTanks();
```

Чтобы при нажатие на пункт меню менялся фрагмент в контейнере content_main.xml создал FrameLayout с id container.
в onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) задаю действие по нажатию на пункт меню

```
int id = item.getItemId();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (id == R.id.nav_pipes) {
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentPipes);
} else if (id == R.id.nav_tanks) {
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentTanks);
}
```

После запуска приложения при выборе в drawer соответствующего пункта с одним из этих фрагментов не происходит замены фрагмента. Ошибок никаких не получаю, просто ничего не происходит.

Весь код выложил
[Calculator](https://github.com/Zets-swe/Calculator)

Comment: я не думаю, что кто-либо захочет читать полный код вашего приложения. Локализуйте проблему, и выложите проблеммный код сюда, сделайте хоть что-нибудь со своей стороны для решения проблемы.

Comment: Прошу прощение за некорректную постановку задачи. Первый раз тут задаю вопрос. Загвоздка в том что я не подозреваю где проблемная часть кода, поэтому решил что неправильно тут писать простыни кода всего проекта. Особенно с учетом того что студия создает вложенные друг в друга xml как матрешка. Я готов исправить постановку как надо, только вот не знаю как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, у вас в том, что вы не вызываете `commit()` над транзакцией добавления фрагмента

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, забыл commit. Большое спасибо!